# WebKit animation on start

Tags: css, animation, webkit

I've set WebKit keyframes on :hover and element is transforming as it should. Reversed effect should be activated when user removes his mouse cursor from element (basically onmouseover and onmouseout in JS).

So I've created reverse keyframes and put them in default CSS selector. Problem is that these keyframes activate on page load, but I need them to be activated only if you move mouse from the element.

Is there some other property that needs to be set or is this achieveable only with JS?

EDIT: Here is JSFiddle test case (view in WebKit, ofcourse): http://jsfiddle.net/nkEwQ/

Comment: can you post some code or jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**without JS:**
removed `-webkit-animation-name:bouncedown;` from `#button`,
replaced it with `-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;`
(can't get the nice bounce effect, but it animates back to the square)
http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/nkEwQ/7/

**With JS**
i removed the animation from `#button`, created a class that handles the webkit animation (`.active`), and added that class on button mouseover using jQuery.

This way, the #button has no animation on load, but the animation declarations are added to it when the user mouses over it.

see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/nkEwQ/5/

Comment: So there's no other way except using JS to add class? This was my first idea, but I thought about asking for solution without JS.

Comment: @Ivan: check the new example.  its getting close. and no JS

Comment: Yup, also thought about that, but it feels natural to also have bounce on mouse out, so I think I will stick with JS solution.

Comment: hmmm... i keep thinking there's a better solution.  it will be  a common problem with css transitions, so there's bound to be a better method.   I'll keep this question in mind f i run into it. good luck coding!

Answer (score 1):

JS only. Cause there are no other pseudo-classes except
:active,
:focus,
:first-child,
:hover,
:lang,
:link,
:visited.